# How to solve socket exception in firebase storage?

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile-development

SocketException (SocketException: Failed host lookup: 'firebasestorage.googleapis.com' (OS Error: No address associated with hostname, errno = 7))

Comment: SocketException occurs when there's a bad internet connection. Make sure you're connected to a stable network. You can however handle the exception by wrapping your method statements in a try...catch block.